Add headers from kafka records to mongo field using sink connector
Im using a mongo sink connector to sink data from kafka topic to mongo collection, all i need is to add headers from these Kafka record to some field in the mongo record.
Its ok if I can map each header by specifying  name or all the headers in one go.
Im not using confluent cloud.

Could you share some example of kafka records?
